# How can I understand this phrase?

Tags: grammaire

Recently I came across the phrase « Il n'a garde d'en assoupir la douleur » which according to DeepL, translates to " it does not dull the pain". I assume that the ne garde is just a rare negative construction, similar to ne point. However, I'm having real trouble trying to unravel the d'en assoupir part, can someone help clarify that?

Comment: @Lambie *Certaines d'entre eux*: Are you sure?

Comment: Here is an entire essay on n'avoir garde: https://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_1942_num_67_267_3541 The first line states: La locution n'avoir garde, très ancienne dans la langue, semble inquiéter les Français d'aujourd'hui ou certains d'entre eux. :) The first meaning some guy he quotes says it comes to mean: ne pas avoir crainte de //It goes on from there. Too bad, can't copy and paste the salient points. {Some people instead of saying, you have a typo, have to go on and on and on. Listen up: I am the queen of typos. So don't ask me.)

Comment: @Lambie Je n'avais pas lu l'article. J'aurais soupçonné une faute de frappe si tu n'avais pas fait immédiatement suivre l'expression douteuse par un smiley. Que tu sois la reine des fautes, je te l'accorde bien volontiers mais je ne pensais pas que ça déteindrait jusqu'aux citations.

Comment: N’avoir garde de faire une chose, n’avoir pas la volonté ou le pouvoir de la faire, en être bien éloigné. Il n’a garde de tromper, il est trop honnête homme. Dans un remerciement. Je n’aurai garde d’oublier ce que je vous dois. https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9G0233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La phrase fait référence à Kierkegaard :

> *Cette épine qu’il se sent au cœur, il n’a garde d’en assoupir la douleur. Il la réveille au contraire et, dans la joie désespérée d’un crucifié content
> de l’être, construit pièce à pièce, lucidité, refus, comédie, une catégorie du démoniaque.*
> Albert Camus, *Le Mythe de Sisyphe*, 1942

C'est une tournure très littéraire qui n'est plus guère utilisée (et est souvent incomprise) aujourd'hui.

*Garde* n'est pas une particule négative rare combinée avec *ne* comme l'est *ne ... point* mais fait partie de la locution *n'avoir garde de*.

[TLFi : **Garde**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/garde)

> *N'avoir garde de* + infinitif (littéraire). Avoir soin d'éviter de. *En toute occasion il n'avait garde de contredire sa fille* (Mérimée, *Colomba*, 1840, p. 155). *L'habitant des villes n'a garde d'approcher de cet homme farouche* (Michelet, *Peuple*, 1846, p. 62) :
> 3. *Je n'ai garde d'oublier ces noms qu'Anna citait avec vénération et qui s'auréolaient dans mon esprit d'un grand prestige.* Gide, *Si le grain*, 1924, p. 366.

Assoupir est une variante littéraire d'endormir.

Le sens de la phrase est donc :

> *Il n'essaie pas d'atténuer la douleur provoquée par cette épine.*
> *Il fait son possible pour que la douleur persiste*.

Comment: Tu es sûr du sens? https://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_1942_num_67_267_3541

Comment: @Lambie Oui, il fait son possible pour que la douleur persiste.

Comment: @Lambie Fréfré s'était trompé dans sa première réponse qu'il a effacée depuis.

Answer (score 1):

Assoupir la douleur = calmer la douleur, soulager la douleur

« En » fait référence à ce qui est douloureux —> assoupir la douleur **de quelque chose**.

Il manque le contexte pour savoir à quoi « en » fait référence.